# Store output of images processed with magick in parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have hundreds of images that I need to reformat using the `magick` package. I've written a function that uses `parLapply` from the `parallel` package to modify the images and store them in a list. However, when I try to view any of the images in the resulting list, I get:
`Error: Image pointer is dead. You cannot save or cache image objects between R sessions.`
When I use the same function with a regular `lapply` statement, the function works as intended, so I know it has something to do with my attempt to process in parallel.

Here is a small reprex. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
# Load images.
img_url <- c("https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/ce3/puppies-1-1308839.jpg",
             "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/006/young-dachshund-1362378.jpg")


img_fun <- function (img) {
    
    # Set up parallel environment.
    require(parallel)
    cl <- makeCluster(2)
    clusterEvalQ(cl, {
        library(tidyverse)
        library(magick)
    })
    
    # Process images.
    parLapply(cl, img, function (i) {
        image_read(i) %>%
            image_rotate(90)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

{magick} uses external pointers that can't be serialized, which means they can't be sent across R processes.

A solution would be to store them to disk, return nothing, and then read all the results afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a try. In the future, this would be better suited as a comment rather than an answer, as there's no working solution provided.

Comment: Also, it seems like the I/O time of this solution would eat into the speed gain achieved by parallelizing the function.